# sql dynamic table creation with variable columns

Tags: sql

I have a table that actually already is neatly structured, but I need to change the output format. The initial table is of the format

```
Class Type Value
c1      t1    1
c2      t1    2
c3      
c1      t2    3
c2      t2    2
c3      t2    5
c2      t3    1
c3      t4    6
c1      t1    9
c2      t1    2
```

I need to dynamically create a table that has the different classes as rows, the types as columns and sums the values. the types are not fixed, so I can't build a static table. How can I dynamically create a table that looks like

```
class    t1    t2    t3    t4
c1       10     3     0     0
c2        4     2     1     0
c3        0     5     0     6
```

Is there a way to do that rather easily with sql?

As I was pointed to pivot, I had a look into it just to learn that mysql is not supporting this. what is the easiest and most straightforward way in sql to mimic pivot?

Comment: is the number types fixed to 4 items t1,t2,t3 and t4. if yes its easy to use a pivot

Comment: Since the types are not fixed, you will need a PIVOT or CROSSTAB syntax. Not all RDBMS support this type of feature. Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: mysql, which unfortunately does not support pivot as I learned

Answer (score 1):

If the number types are fixed to 4 (t1,t2,t3 and t4). We can do this without `PIVOT`:

Try this:

```
SELECT class,
      COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN Type='t1' THEN Value END),0) AS t1,
      COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN Type='t2' THEN Value END),0) AS t2,
      COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN Type='t3' THEN Value END),0) AS t3,
      COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN Type='t4' THEN Value END),0) AS t4
FROM TableName
GROUP BY class
```

Result:

```
CLASS   T1  T2  T3  T4
c1      10  3   0   0
c2      4   2   1   0
c3      0   5   0   6
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6b7b/7).

Comment: Why MAX and not SUM? And how is this supposed to handle the dynamic list of types?

Comment: Coalesce is more general than IfNull, IsNull, Nvl; Coalesce is supported by almost every DBMS

Comment: unfortunately, t's are not fixed. but pivot seems to be the way to go. was not aware of this feature. thanks

Comment: @chrise: Its always good to learn more. Start from [**here**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) or [**here**](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query).

Answer (score 1):

If there're *4 types* (i.e. t1, t2, t3, t4) *only*, try ***case*** construction, something like that:

```
  select class,
         sum(case 
               when Type = 't1' then
                 value
               else
                 0
             end) as t1, 
         sum(case 
               when Type = 't2' then
                 value
               else
                 0
             end) as t2,
         sum(case 
               when Type = 't3' then
                 value
               else
                 0
             end) as t3,
         sum(case 
               when Type = 't4' then
                 value
               else
                 0
             end) as t4     
    from MyTable
group by class
```

In general case (if t1..tn are not fixed) you have to ***pivot***

Comment: t'2 are not fixed. Thanks for pointing out pivot. I was not aware of this feature. a quick google search makes it look like pivot could be my solution